# How to put a numpy norm condition in loop?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I'm trying to implement a Gradient Descent method with optimal step in python, but i get this error :

```py
AttributeError: 'Float' object has no attribute 'sqrt'

if (np.linalg.norm(np.array(dk)) < eps): break

  File <__array_function__ internals>:200 in norm

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py:2512 in norm
    ret = sqrt(sqnorm)

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Float which has no callable sqrt method
```

Here is my code:

```py
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np

def grad(f):
    X = f.free_symbols
    Y = [f.diff(xi) for xi in X]
    return [x_k for x_k in X], Y

def descente_pas_opti(f, X0, eps = 1e-6):
    Xk = X0
    fonction = sp.sympify(f)
    X, gradform = grad(fonction)
    r=sp.symbols('r')
    dform= np.array([-df_k for df_k in gradform])
    
    while True:
        dk=np.array(
            [df_k.subs(
                [(X[k],Xk[k]) for k in range(len(X))])
                    for df_k in dform]
            )
        
        rho = sp.solve(
            np.dot(
                [df_k.subs(
                    [(X[k], Xk[k] + r*dk[k]) for k in range (len(X))] )
                        for df_k in gradform]
                , dk)
            , r)[0]
        
        Xk = [Xk[0]+rho*dk[0], Xk[1]+rho*dk[1]]

        if (np.linalg.norm(dk) < eps): break
        
    return Xk
```

I tried some individual tests outside the loop and all of them work, which means that I have an issue with calling the norm method inside the loop.

also, np.linalg.norm(dk), when computed outside the loop, returns ~25.07 on the first iteration, which is what I expected, but when it is in the loop it doesn't work.

Here are the parameters i gave :

```py
descente_pas_opti('5*x**2 + 0.5*y**2 -3*(x + y)', [-2,-7])
```

Comment: what's `dk` inside the loop, when it fails?  `norm`, with calls to `np.sqrt` only works with numeric arrays.  If `dk` has sympy objects, symbols or expressions you'll get this error.

Comment: @hpaulj that was the issue, i had to convert the elements inside of dk to floats, thanks for helping.

Comment: the usage of `norm` is here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, I needed to add dtype = np.float32 in dk :

```py
dk=np.array(
            [df_k.subs(
                [(X[k],Xk[k]) for k in range(len(X))])
                    for df_k in dform]
            ,dtype = np.float32)
```